# Intillisense fails on undefined namespace in XAML on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I must be brain dead. I have tried for six hours now (with Google) and can not solve this very very simple problem.

In Visual Studio 2010, I created a project. (right-click on solution, Add new project...).

1. Inside the new project, I created a new folder of name Helpers. To the folder I added a class for a converter.
2. Inside the project, I added a new XAML window (in WPF). The Target Framework is .Net Framework 4.0
3. Everything has been built (multiple times) without compilation errors. The platform target build for the project is X86.

The problem:  Intellisense does not see the namespace for the class under the Helpers folder and so the Visual Designer fails. The namespace in the Helpers folder is:

```
  Chaos.UI.Helpers
```

and trying to reference this namespace in the XAML like:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Chaos.UI.Helpers"
```

ofcourse results in the dreaded:

```
Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'Chaos.UI.Helpers' that is not included in the assembly.
```

These are clean files in the same project. The only added code is in the converter class contained in the Chaos.UI.Helpers namespace.

How do I fix this?  (I need the designer to work).

Anybody, Plz help

Answer (score 0):

Try use [assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx#Mapping_To_Custom_Classes_and_Assemblies)

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Chaos.UI.Helpers;assembly=Chaos.UI"
```